# Play video with controls with AVPlayer in collectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Is it possible to play a video with default controls in a collection view? I have a video in a collection view that plays in entire screen. Do i really need to add custom button or I can embed the controls? This is my code that I am trying to implement.Is there any ways to show controls with this?

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
   }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let model = questions[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: VideoCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! VideoCollectionViewCell
    //self.setUpPlayer(url:model)
    cell.configureVideo(videoURL: model)
    cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    return cell
    }
        


import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
class VideoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "VideoCollectionViewCell"
    var player: AVPlayer?
    //private var model:VideoModel?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    public func configureVideo(videoURL:String){
        player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: videoURL)!)
         let playerView = AVPlayerLayer()
         playerView.player = player
        playerView.frame = contentView.bounds
        playerView.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
         contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerView)
         player?.volume = 3
         player?.play()
        
    }

}
```

trying to add controls code.

```
    //    func setUpPlayer(url: String){
//        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: url)!)
//        let avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
//        avPlayerViewController.player = player
//        avPlayerViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
//        self.addChild(avPlayerViewController)
//        //self.view.addSubview(avPlayerViewController.view)
//        collectionView?.addSubview(avPlayerViewController.view)
//        avPlayerViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
//
//    }
```

Comment: Ther commented code looks correct. Make sure to store the `avPlayerController` in a property. Else it will be `nil`after `setUpPlayer()`ends. Which maybe your issue. But we can only guess that. I sugest to improve your question with compilable, uncommented code and proper description of a) what you want to happen and b) what exactly happens.

Comment: @shallowThought
 I have a collection view cell that scrolls vertically like TikTok application. I wanted to display the player controls in it. I can see the video playing in full screen but not any player controls.